# Parent state not updating after function fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, state, axios

I have declared the state in the parent to determine whether a use is logged in or not as per below

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   isLoggedIn: false
  }
 }

 render() {
  <div>
   {
    (document.cookie && this.state.isLoggedIn) ? (
     <LoggedInHeader/>
    ) : <HomeHeader/>
   }
```

In order for a user to be logged in I make an axios request to an api that in turn gives me a token that I store in the browser cookie, the code below is from my log in modal component, I explicitly update the state after the axios request is made to true, the state updates in the console as I would expect but when I check whether the boolean is true or false it is in the original state. I am aware that "setState() does not immediately mutate this.state" but still can't seem to get the state to change. Login form component below which is a child of the app parent.

```
loginSubmitHandler = (event) => {
event.preventDefault()

const user = "email=" + this.state.email + '&password=' + this.state.password

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://weburl',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});

instance.post('/login', user)
  .then(res => {
    let d = new Date
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30)

    let expires = "expires=" + d

    document.cookie = "sessionname" + "=" + res.data.success.token + expires + ";path=/"
    console.log('changing state')
    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: true
    }, () => {console.log('New state', this.state)})
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err, "There was an error")
})}
```

Comment: You are storing the `isLoggedIn` state in App component. So after login it is that state that you have to update. Instead you are setting state in child component `LoginForm`. Try updating parent state by passing down a function as props to LoginForm

Comment: Do states not pass down to child components? If so I then need to change it so the function is called in the App component and set the state in there, as that is where I control the layouts?

Comment: no, each component will have their own state. and what you are doing is correct. Dont take the api call to App. do it in loginForm itself and update state in parent using a function passed down as prop.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this was overthinking the function itself, still getting the hang of props and states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass function to your form component from your `App` component and then trigger it. Actually, `state` is internal object of every component so it can't be updated directly from another one, except using callback function.

For instance:

```
class App extends Component {
    setAuthStatus = status => {
        this.setState({
            isLoggedIn: status,
        })
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    (document.cookie && this.state.isLoggedIn) ?
                        <LoggedInHeader/> : <HomeHeader/>
                }

                <LoginForm setAuthStatus={this.setAuthStatus}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And then call it in your form

```
loginSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const user = "email=" + this.state.email + '&password=' + this.state.password

    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://weburl',
        timeout: 1000,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });

    instance.post('/login', user)
        .then(res => {
            let d = new Date
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30)

            let expires = "expires=" + d

            document.cookie = "sessionname" + "=" + res.data.success.token + expires + ";path=/"
            console.log('changing state')
            this.props.setAuthStatus(true)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err, "There was an error")
        })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, although I have a container component for the login and signup form, so I need to then pass it down to both of those children afterwards (definitely overthought this)

Comment: You can create this function in your container and pass it to the several components (forms in your case).

Comment: I have passed down the function to the correct component now and can update it with an onClick handler with a button but can call it in my function with 'this.props.setAuthSatus(true)' The component class is a class that extends from React

Comment: Don't worry i've figured it out now!

Comment: @EikHunter great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parent state as a prop to the child component.

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false
        }
    }
    render(){
        const {isLoggedIn} = this.state;
        return (
            <Child isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
        )
    }
}
```

Or you can implement the logic inside the render.

```
render(){
    const {isLoggedIn} = this.state;
    if(isLoggedIn){
        return <LoggedInHeader />
    }
    return <HomeHeader />
}
```